# aplicar filtro em retorno de uma lista

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda, linq-to-entities

Estou a fazer uma consulta onde tenho um *array* de situações ex: 1, 2, 3 na consulta tenho que filtrar por essas situações, segue meu código.

```
var array = GetSituacoes();
var lista = bll.Query(p => p.Contrato.PessoaFisica.ID == SessionControl.PessoaFisica.ID);
```

tenho que filtrar a lista pelas as situações que estão no *array*, grato a todos pelo seu tempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Se você esta utilizando Dapper pode fazer da seguinte maneira;

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Pessoa WHERE id = @id"
var results = conn.Query(sql, new { id = SessionControl.PessoaFisica.ID });
```

Se você estiver utilizando EntityFramework pode filtrar da seguinte maneira:

```
public IQueryable<PessoaFisica> GetPessoaFisica(int id)
{
    using(var context = new MyContext()){ 
        return context.PessoaFisica.Where(p => p.id = id).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `Contains` para filtrar a lista de acordo com as situações que estão no `array`, assim:

```
var array = GetSituacoes();
var lista = bll.Query(p => p.Contrato.PessoaFisica.ID == SessionControl.PessoaFisica.ID);
var lista = lista.Where( a => array.Contains(a.Contrato.Situacoes));
```